# Where can I download org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.jar

Tags: java, twitter

I am trying to get a simple application running that connects to Twitter and pulls out the timeline, but i am failing in the basic stuff. I am using Spring-Social to do that and the documentation says that this code should work in creating a connection:

```java
TwitterConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new TwitterConnectionFactory("consumerKey", "consumerSecret");
OAuth1Operations oauth1Operations = connectionFactory.getOAuth1Operations();
String requestToken = oauth1Operations.fetchRequestToken("callbackUrl");
String authorizeUrl = oauth1Operations.buildAuthorizeUrl(requestToken, OAuth1Parameters.NONE);
response.sendRedirect(authorizeUrl);
// when the provider callback is received with the oauth_token and oauth_verifier parameters:
OAuthToken accessToken = oauth1Operations.exchangeForAccessToken(new AuthorizedRequestToken(oauthToken, oauthVerifier));
Connection<TwitterApi> connection = connectionFactory.createConnection(accessToken);
```

However, when I run it in debug, when it hits the third line it throws a class "AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest" not found exception. I have included the "org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.class" , but I need the one with the extra 'Buffered' word and I can't find it anywhere. pls help.

Answer (score 0):

I would skip using the `Connect` Framework and just instantiate the `TwitterApi` directly. Keep life simple, especially if you are only interested in retrieving your timeline.

```
public void GetMyTimeline()
{
  TwitterApi twitterApi = new TwitterApi(
    consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret);

  TwitterProfile myProfile = twitterApi.userOperations().getUserProfile();

  System.out.printf("Id: %s, Name: %s, ScreeName: %s\n",
    profile.getId(), profile.getName(), profile.getScreenName());

  List<Tweet> tweets = twitterApi.timelineOperations().getPublicTimeline();
  // Iterate over tweets List for the 20 most recent public tweets.

  // Do other API calls here...
}
```

The long list of JAR files imported into my project in order for it to compile and run correctly:

[image]

Comment: so what is the connect framework for and if all I am doing is public tweets retrievals, why do I need the consumer key and secret key and the access token at all?

Comment: The `TwitterApi` class uses the `Connect` framework, it is supposed to be easier to use since it takes care of setting up the `Connect` code for you. You have to authenticate to retrieve timelines, so that is why consumer key, consumer secret, access token and token secret are required. You don't have to authenticate to use the `Search` api, but that is for like "current trends", "daily trends", and for searching by query. I don't use Twitter much, so hopefully this is all helpful to some degree. :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this class is available in [3.1.0.M2](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M2/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.html) release of spring.  You can read here on how to obtain the artifacts related to this using maven/ivy [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#d0e689).